# Restricting duplicate attribute values in file geodatabase feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, feature-class, duplication

I have created a File Geodatabase with around 9 feature datasets, and each of those have their own feature classes. So for one of the point feature classes in my GDB, I want to **restrict the entering of duplicate values** in only ***some*** of the fields in this particular feature class.

For example: I capture a point, now I need to fill out the following attributes for that point: 'Force_Number', 'Weekday', and 'Neighborhood'.
I want the 'Force_Number' field to restrict me from entering any values that I have entered for previously captured points in this feature class, and I don't want them to auto increment. But I still want 'Weekday' and 'Neighborhood' to accept duplicate values.

Any Suggestion? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this should be possible in ArcGIS. Have a look at [Enforcing unique values in field when editing in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/132530/115). But it works not for file geodatabases and only for the ArcSDE as described there, too.

To restrict some values you can work with domains for the attributes.